# create category for widgets in elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I made a category for widgets based on [this page](https://developers.elementor.com/docs/widgets/widget-categories/), but it is only possible to specify ID, name and icon, and my category is placed at the bottom of the list. How can I position the category at the top of the list?

I haven't found any way to specify where the category is in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this solution working for me.

```
function custom_elementor_widget_categories( $elements_manager ) {
    $categories = [];
    $categories['your-category-slug'] =
        [
            'title' => 'Your Category Name',
            'icon'  => 'fa fa-plug'
        ];
    $old_categories = $elements_manager->get_categories();
    $categories = array_merge($categories, $old_categories);

    $set_categories = function ( $categories ) {
        $this->categories = $categories;
    };
    $set_categories->call( $elements_manager, $categories );
}
add_action( 'elementor/elements/categories_registered', 'custom_elementor_widget_categories') ;
```

Please assign at lest one widget to your widget categories.

Hope this work for you!

Comment: that's work. thanks!